# FastAPI websocket client

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I've written websocket clients with Twisted and Aiohttp before. But with FastAPI I'm unable to find documentation on how I can setup a *client connection*. I'm not looking for the test client because as far as I can see this is not async. It appears to be requests under the hood.

I'm looking for an example similar to this: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#websockets

Comment: I'm assuming a client ws connection from within a fastapi function to another system? Couldn't you use the websockets library, I think it's async compatible? There's also httpx

Comment: FastAPI websocket can only receive connections. You`ll have to use another library as client

Comment: FastAPI uses Starlette, which under the hood uses `websockets`. If you don't want to add an additional dependency, I suggest using that.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem @Sjuul Janssen?

Comment: I used the `websockets` package as suggested by @Jonathan